# qgis2web 3.7(qgis 3.4.5), cannot replace search box text, cannot see basemap

Tags: qgis2web

I have qgis2web 3.7 with qgis 3.4.5. There were two problems that I had.

1. Whenever I tried to export web map through qgis2web, the basemap was always missing. So, I had to add manually in html.[image]
2. I wanted to change the default text in search box from "Search" to something link"Input an address to search" by changing code in index.html but it didn't show change on the page at all:

   var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder({
           collapsed: false,
           position: 'topleft',
           text: 'Search',
           title: 'Testing'
       }).addTo(map);
   [image]